# Add attribute below product name in cart and invoice - Magento 2

Tags: attributes, cart, magento-2.1.9

**I want to add the color attribute in the cart info and most importantly in the invoice for the product.**

The product has a color attribute assigned for search but it's not an option to select so it doesn't show up in the product details.

**I'd like to have it show up.**